Angular mat-sidenav initially covers nav-content due to observable in app.component
I am using a mat-sidenav-container which contains a mat-sidenav and a mat-sidenav-content.
The mat-sidenav has some links which should be shown depending on a boolean value in my app.component.ts. Because of this, something goes wrong during rendering, and the side nav is drawn on top of the content, instead of the content being rendered to the right of the side-nav.
Example:

Afer reading a bit, there are more complains about this topic. I learned here that a workaround of the problem is to use the autosize property on mat-sidenav-container, but it comes with some concerns mentioned here.
So I started to play around with another suggestion made on the github page, to "reset" the mode on the mat-sidenav.
This works, but only when I add a delay.
app.compoment.html
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn = await this.authService.isLoggedIn();
    this.isAdmin = await this.authService.isAdmin();
    console.log("app started");
    // when I add a delay of zero milliseconds, my sidenav content is drawn correctly??? 
    //await delayMilliseconds(0);
    this.sidenav.mode = 'side';
  }

for completeness the implementation of delayMilliseconds
export function delayMilliseconds(ms: number): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

So what is going on for darkness with the mat-sidenav? I don't mind to keep my current "hack" with a delay of zero, but I mostly would like to understand better why this goes wrong without the delay. Or better said, why it doesn't just work without resetting the mode. Is it really a bug or am I doing something wrong?
For completeness, the entire app.component.html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span style="margin-left: 5px;">{{title}}</span>
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>
  <button *ngIf="isLoggedIn" type="button" (click)="logout()">
    <mat-icon>logout</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn)" type="button" (click)="login()">
    <mat-icon>login</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container style="height:100vh;">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/home">Home</a>
      <a *ngIf="isLoggedIn" mat-list-item routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
      <a *ngIf="isLoggedIn" mat-list-item routerLink="/customers">Customers</a>
      <a *ngIf="isLoggedIn" mat-list-item routerLink="/projects">Projects</a>
      <a *ngIf="isLoggedIn" mat-list-item routerLink="/usersettings">User settings</a>
      <a *ngIf="isAdmin" mat-list-item routerLink="/admin">Admin</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
    <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>


and the complete app.compoment.ts
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "./auth-service";
import { CustomerService } from './customer-service';
import { KeycloakProfile } from 'keycloak-js';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { delayMilliSeconds as delayMilliseconds } from 'src/common/utils/delay';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;

  title = 'Projects buddy';
  public isLoggedIn : boolean;
  public userProfile: KeycloakProfile | null = null;
  isAdmin = false ;

  constructor(
    private readonly authService : AuthService,
    private customerService : CustomerService,
    ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn = await this.authService.isLoggedIn();
    this.isAdmin = await this.authService.isAdmin();
    console.log("app started");
    await delayMilliseconds(0);
    this.sidenav.mode = 'side';
  }

  async login() {
    if (!this.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log("logging in keycloak");
      await this.authService.login();
    }
  }

  async logout() {
    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log("logging off keycloak");
      await this.authService.logoff();  
    }
  }
}

Concluding words

Without "weird hacks" the mat-nav-list is drawn on top of the mat-nav-content
The first workaround is to add autosize to the mat-sidenav-container, but the layout trashing warning in the offical docs kind of scared me away of that approach
The second workaround of resetting the mode of the mat-sidenav only seems to work when I add a zero delay, which doesn't make sense but I went for it anyway.
Is the weird behavior really caused by a bug in angular material or am I using their compoments in the wrong way? Any suggestions to improve / solve this problem?


As far as I understood, the Side nav component needs to know its dimensions in order to correctly render. The reason why your hack works, is because you actually trigger a new render check with using setTimeout, even when using a timeout of 0 seconds.

The issue is primarily due to the timing of rendering and layout recalculations when dynamic conditions are involved. By using the autosize property, manually triggering change detection, or deferring initialization with ngIf, you can ensure that the layout is correctly recalculated and avoid the content overlap.

@AgotaKristof so I should be able to get this working with *ngIf without using autosize?

Because when I add a BehaviorSubject and put this in the html *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async", and I make sure the this.isLoggedIn$.next(this.isLoggedIn) after I awaited the keycloack checks, it still does not draw correctly.

@bas issue not reproducible stackblitz please replicate the issue in this stackblitz and share back!

@bas The zero-delay setTimeout might still be required to ensure layout recalculates, especially if there are other asynchronous operations.

Thx all. Will keep what I had. Felt like a hack but maybe it's not too bad after all then
